# Is there a way to integrate S3 Bucket with Appsync without using an extra AWS Lambda for checking authorization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-appsync

**My Stack:**

AWS Appsync + AWS Lambda(to Mongodb) + custom OpenId-Connect Provider(also Lambda)

**What I am trying to achieve**

I would like to store some of the user data to the S3 bucket. I am hoping I can access the stored data directly from appsync, instead of calling a lambda for authorization checking **every time I have to access the data.**

**There are mainly two types of information I want to store. For instance, userPicture and userSecret.**

1. userPictures,that can be accessed by anyone.

As there are not access control checking, this part can be achieved by issuing a presignedUrl. No further authorization has to be done.

2. userSecret, that can be accessed by oneself and all admins

Here comes the part that I am trying to avoid calling another lambda just for authorization check. I already have the `userId and role` stored in the `$context.identity`, but still haven't figured out a way to actually perform the checking.

**Is there a way I can avoid the lambda overhead?**

Answer (score 0):

AppSync recently launched support for multiple Authorization Providers. So for example you can secure your userSecret with an OpenID Connect provider and your userPictures by using an Api key. Does that satisfy your use case?